# Postgres break table columns into multiple tables having unique rows

Tags: postgresql, cte, postgresql-9.5

I have this table called `transactions`. It has two columns `id` and `report_id`. `id` is primary key.

I want to create two new tables `transaction_ids` and `report_ids` both with just one column `id`.
Both these new tables are supposed to have the list of unique transaction ids and unique report ids respectively.

The first solution that come to mind is:

```
Step 1:
insert into transaction_ids (select id from transactions); // as `trasnactions.id` is a primary key, uniqueness is guaranteed

Step 2:
insert into report_ids (select distinct report_id from transactions); // using DISTINCT to make sure uniqueness
-- OR --
create unique index on report_ids(id);
insert into report_ids (select report_id from transactions) on conflict(id) do nothing; // using on conflict to make sure of uniqueness
```

The problem here is that I am traversing the `transactions` table twice. I am thinking of this as a for loop where I can just traverse the table once and push both `transaction.id` and `transaction.report_id` to the right table on each iteration (assuming I have the on conflict handling present for the table `report_ids`).

**Question 1**: Is there a way to do it, without actually ending up writing the `for` loop. I don't have anything against `for` loop. It's just I have to write extra lines; the same thing which now I am able to do in just two lines.

**Question 2**: Also, I am worried, that if I insert the rows one by one in side a for loop, would postgres take much time for this as compared to just asking the whole column in one go. In which case, I would have to compare whether the performance gain by traversing just once is worth the performance loss by inserting rows one by one

I also thought of using CTE:

```
with _ as (insert into transaction_ids (select id from transactions))
insert into report_ids (select distinct report_id from transactions);

-- OR --

create unique index on report_ids(id);
with _ as (insert into transaction_ids (select id from transactions))
insert into report_ids (select report_id from transactions) on conflict(id) do nothing;
```

But, IMO even here the problem of traversing twice is present.
**Question 3**: Does this approach has any advantage over first approach

**Question 4**: Is there a recommended/preferred/standard way to deal with this situation?

P.S.: I am worried because size of the `transactions` table is quite big:

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('transactions'));
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 2282 MB
(1 row)

select count(id) from transactions;
  count  
---------
 1465605
(1 row)

select count(report_id) from transactions;
  count  
---------
 1360204
(1 row)

select count(distinct report_id) from transactions;
 count  
--------
 168508
(1 row)
```

Comment: for now, I am just continuing with my first approach, where I fill all transactions ids in first traversal and all report ids on second traversal

Comment: "*I want to create two new tables transaction_ids and report_ids both with just one column id*" - why would you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve with that approach?

Comment: 2GB is not big, the `insert` operations would be fast finished.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this question is a sub-problem of a big problem. I removed all the irrelevant stuff to keep it to the point. As you are interested, a short info in the below comments:

Comment: We have this single table, which is kind of a read-only copy version of multiple source tables(read around 30 tables here) with complex join. Now, we need to keep this table up to date with fresh data. So, at regular intervals(every hour for now) we find the "ids" of interest and then update those rows only. This question is part of the process of finding ids of interest.

Comment: Every night, we do the full refresh, where "ids" of interest are nothing but all the ids.

Think of this as a custom materliazed view

Comment: ^ This does not explain the complete situation, but its like this more or less.

Comment: If the original table is *insert only*, you only need to fetch the *new* ids periodically. (the associated report_ids can either be new or existing)